# Flutter pushAndRemoveUntil wrongly working - push to new screen and removes all the previous screens

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having Dashboard, Reservation Intro Page, Third Screen, Fourth Screen, Fifth Screen.

Users can go back to Reservation Intro page from Third Screen or Fourth Screen or Fifth Screen by clicking a button.

For that, I'm using pushAndRemoveUntil

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              return ReservationIntroPage(
                  sharedPreferences: widget.sharedPreferences);
            }), ModalRoute.withName('/dashboard'));
```

But when I'm clicking a button in Third or fourth or fifth screen, my app taking to Reservation Intro Page, but when I'm pressing back button will closing. That means pushAndRemoveUntil removes all the screens with that Dashboard too.

I'm using onGenerateRoute, this will cause the problem?

I need a dashboard in Stack, I don't know why it's working wrongly.

Comment: Just to clarify, the snippet you posted in the question is inside onGenerateRoute?

Comment: @MarceloWippel No brother, Above code is not written inside onGenerateRoute. Above code is written in third,fourth, fifth screen file. onGenerateRoute is written inside main.dart file and inside MaterialApp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**pushAndRemoveUntil** is working correctly when i'm having all the pages in **routes**.

So i removed all the pages from `onGenerateRoute` and added everything into routes property.

`onGenerateRoute` property have bug that mentioned in Github. [onGenerateRoute Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50192)

Comment: Yes! Your are right but If use the "routes" so how we can get the argument on next screen out side the build method. if I can use this method for getting argument(final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;) So I need the context. So my question is How can we get the argument out side the build method?

Answer (score 0):

As mention in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50192 :

Just add `settings: settings` in your `MaterialPageRoute`

The whole `CustomNavigator` Widget (look for the <=======):

```
 CustomNavigator(
    initialRoute: 'fdp',
    navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
    navigatorObservers: [locator<Analytics>().getAnalyticsObserver(), HeroController()],
    onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
      switch (settings.name) {
        case '/searchPage':
          final SearchPageArguments arguments = settings.arguments;
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SearchPage(matchcode: arguments.matchcode), settings: settings //<=======);
          break;
        default:
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MessageHandler(child: WrapperAfterConnexion()), settings: settings //<=======);
      }
    },
    home: MessageHandler(child: WrapperAfterConnexion()),
)
```